# How to increase the text size in a gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I am dynamically loading a xaml file. This is what the xaml looks like:

```
<ListView  Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="White"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Name="ListView1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=line}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Lines"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=aline}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView >
```

The xaml cannot be changed.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `FontSize` ??

Comment: `<Style><Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="32" /></Style>` - as an example.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that the xaml cannot be changed

Comment: Are you loading this xaml from a file or outside location? If so, parse the file and modify the value before you use it.

Comment: @gunr2171 It is from a file. I only have the file path to it and cannot be changed. But I know that It will be in this format.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 You are correct. FontSize will work. Thank you

Comment: David, I was meaning to modify the file in-memory. @sa_ddam213, you might want to write up a quick answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the `FontSize` in your xaml.

```
<ListView  Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="White" FontSize="20" .................
```

However if you are loading your Xaml from a file you will have to load it first then change the FontSize

Example:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("c:\\test.xaml", FileMode.Open))
{
    var listView = (ListView)XamlReader.Load(stream);

    // change font size
    listView.FontSize = 20;

    // apply listView to whatever you need
}
```